# Implementing Actions on google

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, actions-on-google

What I try to accomplish is let my app be accessible with voice commands on google assistant
I get this error when open App Actions Test tool.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is5wV.png)

[image]

**actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<actions>
    <action intentName="com.example.appname.SHOW_SWITCH_BOARD">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://appname-test-6bc52.firebaseapp.com/{?switchboard}">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="switchboard.name"
                urlParameter="switchboard" />
        </fulfillment>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What were you trying to accomplish and what did you do? We need more information

Comment: Can you update your question to include the actions.xml file you were trying to use, along with any other information that can help us help you debug the problem.

Comment: I have just started the project.What I try to accomplish is let my app be accessible with voice commands on google assistant.Can you suggest any best tutorials?

Comment: The error says :"Missing queryPatterns"
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/action-package/reference/QueryPatterns so where are you suppsed to add them?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `intentName` for your [action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/action-schema#action) tag isn't [one of the supported built-in Intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/intents).

Currently, you can only use one of the pre-defined Intents to trigger your app. If your app is not in one of the categories that they currently have Intents defined for - you cannot implement App Actions.

Here is an additional video from I/O 2019 discussing App Actions: https://youtu.be/vQALSeGy9aY

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.Because I am a nooby, I have some trouble understanding things from the doc that google provided. In case you have any video tutorial about this please share.

Comment: Hope it helps! If a reply has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated. If you're still confused about something - feel free to update your question or ask another one with more details about the issue.

Comment: I've also updated the answer with a link to a video from I/O 2019.